# Starting and Shutting down LAMPP with sudo access

Tags: sudo, lamp

I have read somewhere on net that we can install LAMPP ([apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html)) in such a way that any user can start and/or stop LAMPP server using nobody

Is is possible? Let me know how can I do it?

I want to set permissions so that starting and stopping can be made public.

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking. Do want to know if `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` and `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop` works? Or are you asking whether permissions can be set to make starting/stopping public?

Comment: I want to set permissions so that starting and stopping can be made public

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /opt/lampp/
sudo chmod ugo+rwx lampp
```

That should give everyone full permission.

Comment: You will need to run `chmod` as a superuser

Comment: Good point, I fixed it.